# what can I do to fix my jQuery without any hard-coding in my HTML?

Tags: html, jquery

When I checked my work I see undefined in my work. It's not supposed to be there. Can anyone help?

[image: My work]

jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var listItems = $("#productList li");
    listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
        var product = $(li);
        product.append(" - <b> ("+product.attr('data-type')+") </b>");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="productList">
    <li data-activity-type="family">Snow Tubbing</li>
    <li data-activity-type="family">Snowcat Mountain Tour</li>
    <li data-activity-type="adventure">SnowSlam 11 Racing Course</li>
    <li data-activity-type="adventure">Snowboarding</li>
    <li data-activity-type="adventure">Edge 11 Performance Ski Racing</li>
    <li data-activity-type="family">Dog Sled Tour</li>
    <li data-activity-type="family">Snowshoeing</li>
    <li data-activity-type="kids">Kid's Night Out</li>
    <li data-activity-type="kids">Bear Cub Kamp at the Nursery</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `activity-type` value is going to append to innerHTML.
the `data-type` should be `data-activity-type`.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var listItems = $("#productList li");
    listItems.each((index, item) => {
      item = $(item);
      item.html( item.html() + `- <b>${ item.attr('data-activity-type') }</b>` );
    });
  });
```

Comment: haha I totally missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you can use `data()` function, instead of `attr`. like so: ```item.html( item.text() + `- <b>${ item.data('activity-type') }</b>` );```